# How can we use custom attribute to assign a value to a field?

Tags: c#, custom-attributes

I am very new to C# and a beginner in custom attributes.

I have two questions:

```
[FindsBy(How = How.xpath, Using = "//*[@id='test']")]
public IWebElement BTN_Position;
```

1. With this code how does `BTN_Position` get initialized? Is `FindsBy` returning some value and assigning those to the field?
2. I am writing a custom attribute. Can I do something kind of returning a value at the end and assign to a field?

Something like: `Test` attributes takes two positional parameters and does something and `return`s a `string` combining two `string`s. When I use code like below, it should be assigned to `FullName`.

```
[TestAttribute("Firstname", "Lastname")]
public string FullName;
```

Answer (score 4):

Attributes are used as metadata *only*. They’re classes, so they can have functions, etc, but those functions won’t get called automatically. You have to use reflection to to get an instance of an attribute at which point you could call those functions.

For example, the `HttpPost` attribute from ASP.NET MVC doesn’t actually *do* anything except hold data. MVC reflects over controller methods looking for that attribute and then registers the method in the router according to values declared on that attribute instance.

Comment: Without using reflections is there any way ? Reflections are obsolete in .NET Core.

Comment: Reflection is not obsolete in .NET Core. I use it there daily. To what do you refer?

Comment: Worth noting that you may have to use typeof(T).GetTypeInfo() in .net Core to actually get to the reflection stuff.

Comment: I am trying to replace PageFactory with a custom attribute. FindsBy is part of PageFactory.

Comment: Then I suggest you create a class, say FindsByBasedPageProvider, which can scan assemblies looking for classes which have methods with you FindsBy attribute, register them to be looked up, and expose a method for creating a page based on the info found in FindsBy.